# NoReverseMatch Error Django - UpdateView

Tags: django

I have a view which the user can create/update their posts. However, when the user has finished their editing, I want them to return back to the post (summary). However, there's an error somewhere which I can't find. Any ideas on what the issue may be?

Error: **1) Reverse for 'aircraftdetail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'id': 2}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []**

**2) return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())**

**3) return reverse('aircraftdetail', kwargs={"id": self.id})**

**views.py**

```
def AircraftUpdate(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Aircraft, id=id)
    form = AircraftForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    context={"aircraft":instance, "form":form}
    return render(request,'aircraft_form.html',context)
```

**Models.py**

```
class Aircraft(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'static/image_upload', blank=True)
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)

def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('aircraftdetail', kwargs={"id": self.id})
```

**Urls.py - Aircraft**

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^detail/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.AircraftDetail, name='AircraftDetail'),
  url(r'^detail/(?P<id>\d+)/edit/$', views.AircraftUpdate, name='AircraftEdit'),
  url(r'^$', views.AircrafList, name='aircraft'),]
```

**Urls.py AviationSite (Main)**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'aircraft/', include('aircraft.urls')),
    url(r'^login/', login_view, name="login"),
    url(r'^logout/', logout_view, name="logout"),
    url(r'^register/', register_view, name="register"),
    url(r'^aircraft/create/$', AircraftCreate),]
```

Comment: In Python, the recommended practice is to call your view function `aircraft_update`. Using `AircraftUpdate` makes it look like a class based view to other Django users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your URL pattern has `name='AircraftDetail' (capitalised 'A' and 'D'):

```
url(r'^detail/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.AircraftDetail, name='AircraftDetail'),
```

That does not match the `aircraftdetail` (all lowercase) where you call `reverse`:

```
return reverse('aircraftdetail', kwargs={"id": self.id})
```

Change one of them to make them match (all lowercase is more common in Django).

Comment: I literally feel so stupid right now. Thank you so much for pointing out this small mistake haha